# Search on specific sites only

Tags: support, area-51

Apologies if I'm overlooking something blindingly obvious, but is there a way to perform a network-wide search query on certain sites only?

Like for example, searching for "mySQL vulnerability" on SO, SF, and security.SE. (pulling this out of my arse, my question is about the generic approach to this, not that exact query.)

I'm aware of tag sets but I'm interested in an approach that can directly specify sites.

There's Google's `site:` option that works, but seems to be able to restrict searching to only one site at a time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `or` with the `site` option:

[SO/SF/ITS for `mysql vulnerability`](http://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Asecurity.stackexchange.com+OR+site%3Astackoverflow.com+OR+site%3Aserverfault.com+mysql+vulnerability)